# make all js and css files pass through php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a shared hosting that does not enable `mod_expires`. So I am trying to make all of my CSS and JS files pass through a PHP file that adds a required header, but I can't get it to work. I tried the solution given on [this site](https://www.warpconduit.net/2010/10/23/enabling-gzip-compression-of-php-css-and-js-files-without-mod_deflate/).

I have the following:

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*\.js) gzip.php?type=js&file=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*\.css) gzip.php?type=css&file=$1
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$allowed = array('css','js'); //set array of allowed file types to prevent abuse

//check for request variable existence and that file type is allowed
if(isset($_GET['file']) && isset($_GET['type']) && in_array(substr($_GET['file'],strrpos($_GET['file'],'.')+1), $allowed)){
    $data = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$_GET['file']); // grab the file contents

    $etag = '"'.md5($data).'"'; // generate a file Etag
    header('Etag: '.$etag); // output the Etag in the header

    // output the content-type header for each file type
    switch ($_GET['type']) {
        case 'css':
            header ("Content-Type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
        break;

        case 'js':
            header ("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset: UTF-8");
        break;
    }

    header('Cache-Control: max-age=300, must-revalidate'); //output the cache-control header
    $offset = 60 * 60;
    $expires = 'Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',time() + $offset) . ' GMT'; // set the expires header to be 1 hour in the future
    header($expires); // output the expires header

    // check the Etag the browser already has for the file and only serve the file if it is different
    if ($etag == $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
        header('Content-Length: 0');
    } else {
        echo $data;
    }
}
?>
```

But for some reason it's not working.